# How to make a Fedora respin that has a custom program icon on its desktop?

Tags: fedora, livecd, kickstart

I want to create a Fedora custom Live DVD that ships with an icon to a custom program (not in any repository, it's something I made) appearing on the desktop, ready to be executed by the user as soon as he boots the DVD and the desktop appears. I'm using this page as a guide:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD

But it's unclear how I would include a custom file like that in the generated ISO. Is it some directive in the .ks file? Where should I place the file, and how do I specify that I want a link to this file on the live user's desktop? Would it help if I made an RPM out of it?

Comment: Does the official [Fedora Spins page](http://spins.fedoraproject.org/support) help? The wiki there should be the starting point...

Answer (score 2):

You will need the contents of the `.desktop` file that opens your program.

In the kickstart file for your spin look for the line:

```
cat >> /etc/rc.d/init.d/livesys << EOF
```

After that line you can insert your mydesktop file as so: (my example is the `.desktop` file from the  browser.  Note the FOE Can't be EOF.

```
cat >> /usr/share/applications/surf.desktop << FOE
[Desktop Entry]
Name=surf
Comment=small and simple browser
Categories=Network;GTK;WebBrowser;
Exec=surf
Icon=surf
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-Desktop-File-Install-Version=0.23
FOE

#just in case it doesn't exist...
mkdir ~liveuser/Desktop/

#then also put that .desktop file on the Liveuser's desktop
cp /usr/share/applications/surf.desktop /home/liveuser/Desktop/
```

If you actually need to copy some files, ie a program to your spin that isn't an rpm, you can make an nfs export on your local machine, and put the files you want copied in there.  Then put the following just before the `%end` label of your kickstart file.

```
mount -t nfs4 localhost:/myshare /mnt
mkdir /usr/local/install
cp -pr /mnt/* /usr/local/install/

%end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this. I assume you know how to create rpms

1. Create the rpm for the said package.
2. Create a repo using the createrepo tool
3. add your repo to your kickstart file like so

   ```
   repo --name=nameofrepo --baseurl=yoururltoyourrepo
   ```
4. then just add the package in your kickstart file

Hope that helps